# How can I quickly add a missing namespace in VS Code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, namespaces, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying my best to start really using VS Code (I come from Visual Studio environment).  In VS I can just right click a red squiggle and add the namespace.  In VS Code it can be done quickly but I can't remember how.  I think it had something to do with the single quote key maybe?  I do have OmniSharp enabled and running if that matters.

Is there somewhere that would tell me these shortcuts?  Like a cheat sheet for VS Code?  I don't see it on the one shown below...
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `CTRL`+`.` on the word with the red underline. No need to install other extensions.

Comment: I knew it was something simple like this!  Thanks!!  Is there somewhere this is documented at?  I have spent hours looking online for it and apparently I had no idea what to look for.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it is the same shortcut as Visual Studio.

Comment: Just incase anyone else cares, apparently this is called the `Quick fix` shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

CTRL + SHIFT + D
Aradığın cevap bu olabilir.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install "C# extensions" extension, the project is not anymore under development but it will do its job.

Comment: Which one?  There is like 5 of them by various users.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac  you use the combination `⌘(cmd)`+`.`